# Why my repo is empty after migrating a svn repo to git?

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

Currently i have a problem while migrating (Permanent usage of Git planned) a svn repo to git. I followed the documentation on Git.

So i tried:
`git svn clone https://srvserver/svn/Produktion/VB/VS2017/EmailVersand --prefix "" --no-metadata --authors-file svn-authors.txt -s EmailVersand`

Also i used the proposed 3 for loops to modify tags and branches.

But i see nothing inside the Repository, just .git.

While cloning i'm got:

> Initialized empty Git repository in EmailVersand/.git/
> Using higher level of URL: https://srvserver/svn/Produktion/VB/VS2017/EmailVersand => https://srvserver/svn/Produktion
> W: Ignoring error from SVN, path probably does not exist: (160013): Filesystem has no item: File not found: revision 100, path '/VB/VS2017/EmailVersand'
> W: Do not be alarmed at the above message git-svn is just searching aggressively for old history.
> This may take a while on large repositories

I also tried "--no-minimize-url": Then i'm getting:

> W: Ignoring error from SVN, path probably does not exist: (160013): Filesystem has no item: '/svn/Produktion/!svn/rvr/100/VB/VS2017/EmailVersand' path not found

I also tried to check the path manually with:
`svn ls https://srvserver/svn/Produktion/VB/VS2017/EmailVersand` it gives me:

> svn ls https://srvserver/svn/Produktion/VB/VS2017/EmailVersand 
> EmailVersand/ 
> EmailVersand.sln 
> LogEmail/ 
> SiB_Versand/

In general i'm expecting a filled folder.

Comment: if I recall correctly, `git-svn` will _not_ checkout anything.... so there will be nothing in the working tree. Try checking out a remote branch and it should work.